# Are questions about Play by E-mail/Play by Web Games allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

Are questions about Play by E-mail/Play by Web Games allowed or is it strictly tabletop, etc?

If we can, is it simply just rules discussions or are we also allowed to ask questions like the best place to advertise your game, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as it's a play by email/web of a tabletop RPG, it's on topic.

And you can ask stuff like "where to advertise  your game" but that'll be a one time community wiki on "best places to advertise a PBeM game," not specific questions/promotion for a specific game...

Comment: I think there are lot of good and useful questions about technique and tool that can be (and have been) asked. As this is a large part of the "tabletop" rpg scene thety definitely belong here.

Comment: That's good enough for me!